# Random Sampling in Excel based on specific criteria from other colums

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a list of file numbers in Column `A`, a code associated with the file in column `B`, and a number of days in column `I`.  Example:

```
File      Code     Days
12345     AAAA     100
54321     AAAA      91
67890     BBBB     115
09876     CCCC     150
```

There are approximately 100+ rows of data.
I would like to pull a random sampling of file numbers based on the following criteria:

- At least 20 files or 20% whichever is greater.
- At least 1 file from each Code.
- All files that have a Code not shared with any other files.
- All files where the Days exceeds 150.

Is this even possible?

Comment: (1) Your third constraint appears to be redundant; if you have at least one file from code `CCCC`, and there is only one file with that code, then, by definition, you have that file. (2) This might be very difficult to do with formulas (a.k.a. worksheet functions). Are VBA solutions acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

The difficulty is that there are many possible ways the sampling can go because of the unknown ratios of things like the file count vs. number of unique codes vs. codes with a single file vs. files > 150 days vs. distribution of the number of files per code, etc.  Rather than trying to design a definitive solution for all possible cases, I'll describe a process that will get you to the solution.  Each step has numerous straightforward ways you can do it in Excel.

Think of it as three pots:

- Pot 1 you will fill with your selected samples over the course of the exercise (this pot will be in the form of a list that you build with the selected filenames).  We'll call this the samples list.
- Pot 2 contains the collection of unique codes (this pot will be in the form of a list of the unique codes; look up how to extract the unique values from a list containing duplicates if you don't know how).  This will contain the codes that have not yet been represented by a selected sample.  We'll call this the codes list.
- Pot 3 contains "tokens" for the required number of samples remaining (this pot will just be a number in a cell that you decrement or tally against as you select the samples).  We'll call this the remaining samples count.  Calculate the greater of 20 or 20% and put that number it this pot.

Here are the steps:

1. Decide what oversampling limit to use.  Your target is 20% of the files but random sampling won't give you a uniform 20% across all codes (unless you add an additional requirement for that).  Some codes will have less than 20% selected, some more.  The non-random rules will bear no relationship to 20%.  Codes with a single file will be 100% sampled.  The >150 days rule could select more than 20% of the files for a given code.  If you select far above 20% by this rule, that code will already be over-represented, so you probably don't want to randomly sample even more from that code.  Decide on a maximum sampling percentage (or sample count) for the >150 days rule beyond which you exclude that code from random sampling.
2. Select all files with days >150 and move them to the samples list.  Decrement the remaining samples count by the count of these files.  Remove the codes represented by these files from the codes list (based on the unique codes for this collection of files).
3. If this step results in any codes exceeding the over-sampling limit, remove all files associated with these codes from the source list.  Note that removal is figurative.  The intent is to ensure that none of those files get sampled later.  You could code that in a way that does not require actually removing the files.
4. Of the remaining files and codes in the codes list, move to the samples list any files where that is the only file for that code.  Decrement the remaining samples count by the count of these files.  Remove the codes represented by these files from the codes list.  Note that this step is not strictly necessary depending on how step 5 is implemented.  I broke this out as a separate step for clarity and so that you don't need to randomly select from a list of one.
5. For each remaining code in the codes list, randomly select one file for that code and move it to the samples list.  Decrement the remaining samples count by the count of these files.  Remove the codes represented by these files from the codes list (removing the codes could be optional, depending on how you implement it; once this step is complete, the codes list is not needed any more).
6. For the number of files in the remaining samples count, randomly select a file from the remaining files and move it to the samples list.

And you're done.

It's beyond the intended scope of a question on this site to design the whole application for you.  There are many ways to approach each step and the formulas and methods to accomplish them are well represented in previous questions on the site.  If you do get stuck, ask a new question for help with the specific problem.  For example, "How do I randomly select a value from a list?" would be the appropriate scale of a question.

Comment: Great answer! A few minor quibbles: (1) My comment on the question seems to apply to your answer as well; your step #4 is redundant, inasmuch as you could delete it, and step #5 would still produce the desired result. (2) “Remove the codes represented by these files from the codes list.” in step #5 appears to be superfluous, because you never reference the codes list again.

Comment: (3) I had to read your answer twice to figure out that “remove all files associated with these codes from the source list” in step #3 means “ensure that you don’t select them in step #6”. (4) The OP says “***At least*** 20 files or 20% …” You might want to add a note that she could increase the size of the sample to get a more uniform distribution.

Comment: on 1. You were correct in the comment on the question, but this step is necessary in the procedure as described to ensure that at least one is selected.  Random doesn't guarantee that. 2. You are correct.  That was intended more to help visualize the process.  It isn't a required coding step. 4. Increasing the sample size won't make it more uniform; using a uniform distribution would make it more uniform.  The OP created the non-random rules to ensure that the desired minimum sampling pattern is met.

Comment: The numbers of files associated with each code could vary widely, so trying to sample uniformly becomes difficult.  I'll edit the answer to incorporate some of your points.

Comment: (1) Step #5 says, “For each remaining code in the codes list, randomly select one file for that code ….” What do you mean, “Random doesn’t guarantee” … “that at least one is selected.”? Step #4 is unnecessary, because, if there are “any files where that is the only file for that code”, then step #5 will randomly select one from a list of one, guaranteeing that any such unique file is selected. (4) No, increasing the sample size won’t make it more uniform, but it will *allow* you to make it more uniform by selecting files where Days ≤ 150 in numbers to counter the unbalance caused by Step #2.

Comment: You were right on point 1.  I went back and clarified that in the answer.  On your other point, the >150 days handling is really a problem that could apply to all of the data.  The number of files per code is not uniform.  Say one code has 2 files and another has 20.  One sample from the 1st code is 50% vs. 5% for the other.  So codes with few files will always be overrepresented.  If more equal code representation is important, some type of proportional sampling would be needed.  Just increasing the random sampling will also increase oversampling for codes with few files.